# In website designing, width and height is varing for each browser.how to prevent this

Tags: html, css, width

I am new to designing the website. I am using chrome in linux. and i have tested my website in chrome in windows. I got one problem like height and width is varying? How to make my website design compatible to all browsers. If this problem come by unit mean Which unit is best like em,px or %?

Comment: Your question does not give the real source code of your website. We cannot help much here. You can make a website which does not strongly depend upon the window's width (which will vary a lot from one user to the next).

Comment: No, this is not a generally known problem. You'll have to be more specific if you need help.

Answer (score 2):

This is an actual design choice. You may use a fixed size, or make your site fluid.

**Fixed size** means that you define the width you want to design for. A very popular choice was 960px, since it is compatible with screens 1024px wide with some room on the sides and a scrollbar.

If you choose this method, you need to have a wrapper element around your whole site (eg a `<div id="wrapper">` right after your `<body>` tag, that closes at the end of your document (essentially all your site goes into that). You can then have the CSS rule :

```
#wrapper { 
  width: 960px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

which will center your whole site horizontally on the screen. The advantage of this method is that since your width is known, you can easily measure and calculate widths for the elements inside (such as sidebars etc). This is extremely convenient when dealing with ad placements.

**Fluid size** means that you define the width as a percentage of the available screen estate. This method used to be mostly for full-width sites, ( imagine the `#wrapper` element above set to `width: 100%`. In my personal opinion, this method on its own is troublesome and only applicable to special cases.

Last but not least, the current trend is for **responsive design**. This method uses CSS [Media queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries) to load different styles depending on the available width, and may use either of the above for the specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue between different browsers. **As a last resort** you can try using css hacks for each browser pair where the changes in sizes are found.

*Example*: 
Here's an easy hack for `IE`, add underscore (_) before css

```
_height:200px;
```

Have a look at [this site.](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/)

*Hope this helps :)*